# super giving the wrong type when subclassing tuple()

Tags: python, inheritance, tuples, super

I tried porting something from python2 to python3, and was confronted with an error concerning the following class:

```
class Bound(tuple):
    # some methods skipped…

    def __new__(cls, value, is_closed):
        if value is NegativeInfinity or value is PositiveInfinity:
            is_closed = False
        return tuple.__new__(cls, (value, is_closed))

    def __init__(self, value, is_closed):
        """
        See __new__
        """
        super(Bound, self).__init__((value, is_closed))
```

When trying to initialize, it would fail with `object.__init__() takes no parameters`.  It appears that `super(Bound, self).__init__(…)` accesses the `__init__` method of `object`, which seems wrong – doesn't `super` just advance at the objects `__mro__`?

To narrow things down, I wrote the following construction:

```
class T(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, arg):
        return super(T, cls).__new__(cls, arg)

    def __init__(self, arg):
        return super(T, self).__init__(arg)
```

In this example, I get the same error: `T([])` tells me `object.__init__() takes no parameters` nonetheless.

Since `T.__mro__` is `(__main__.T, tuple, object)`, this is inherently confusing.  The exact same happens when using `super()` without explicitly stating type and instance.

What goes wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It appears that `super(Bound, self).__init__(…)` accesses the `__init__` method of `object`, which seems wrong – doesn't `super` just advance at the objects `__mro__`?

`object.__init__` *is* the next `__init__` in the MRO, because `tuple` doesn't have its own `__init__`.

On Python 2, this would have given you a (suppressed by default) warning. On Python 3, it's an error. You can either remove your `__init__` method (which, due to special handling in `object.__init__`, will stop `object.__init__` from complaining), or you can call `super(Bound, self).__init__()`, without arguments.

For more details, see the [explanatory comment](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Objects/typeobject.c#L3430) in the Python source code.